# Unable to configure Send to connection

Tags: administration, central-administration

I have 2 site collections and I am trying to configure send to connection from site 1 to site 2. Site 1 is in UK SharePoint farm and site 2 is in US SharePoint farm. I've tried creating a send to connection from UK central admin to US central admin and I am receiving "Verification Failed: URL is not a valid routing URL" and ULS logs shows below errors

System.ArgumentException: Verification Failed: URL is a not a valid routing destination

at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.OfficialFileAdminPage.AddorUpdateConnection()

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

and

Url validation failed for Servername:portnumber/site /_vti_bin/OfficialFile.asmx  during Record and document center connection configuration with exception The request failed with HTTP status 407: Proxy Authorization Required.:

at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.OfficialFileSoap.GetServerInfo()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.OfficialFileAdminPage.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_2()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.OfficialFileAdminPage.IsValidUriToRouter(Uri uriToValidate)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.. by adding proxy settings in central system web.config..

```
<defaultProxy> 
  <proxy proxyaddress="SiteURL:PortNumber"; bypassonlocal="true" /> 
  <bypasslist> 
    <add address="SiteURL\.com$" /> 
  </bypasslist> 
</defaultProxy>
```

Comment: <defaultProxy> <proxy proxyaddress="http://SiteURL:PortNumber" bypassonlocal="true" /> <bypasslist> <add address="SiteURL\.com$" /> </bypasslist> </defaultProxy>

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Content Organizer feature on the Record Center/Document Center site and try again.  That worked for me.  Check here for details:

https://angler.wordpress.com/tag/url-is-not-a-valid-routing-destination/